# NS_ENUM without name

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, enums

This lines are OK in my code:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger,  unused_name)
{   k_a = 123,
    k_b = 123,
    k_c = 61
};
```

But the following lines are not. The compiler complains that the variable (…) part of NS_ENUM doesn't contain any variable.

```
NS_ENUM(NSInteger)
{   k_a = 123,
    k_b = 123,
    k_c = 61
};
```

I have the same problem with a CF_ENUM.

I think it's not a problem of header file (`Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h` or Core Foundation).

Comment: I wrote an answer but it looks like you're doing everything right so far.  Just make sure your enum declarations are outside of any Objective-C interface or implementation code blocks.

Comment: You can't have an NS_ENUM without a name. The name becomes the name of the typedef to be used for the NS_ENUM. Using a non-unique name like "unused_name" gets you into trouble. Not giving a name at all won't work. And it's not a problem with a header - it's a problem with your code. You are doing something wrong, and the compiler tells you.

Comment: @gnasher729 Unless I'm missing something you can in fact have an NS_ENUM without a name (like the second code block in the question).  It just shows up as `enum <anonymous>` in Xcode's code completion.

Comment: At quick glance the code appears legit. What compiler & version are you using? Where in your code are these statements (source, header, inside interface/implementation, etc)?

Comment: @CRD I'm using Xcode 7.3.1. The lines of code are after the interface and before the implementation blocks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, the code is fine. You can try right-clicking the `NS_ENUM` in your code and selecting "Jump to Definition" to see which macro you are calling. Also the menu item "Product > Perform Action > Preprocess" will show you what the file looks like after the macros have been expanded - check to see what is being produced. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Look at the comment in the `NSObjCRuntime.h` header file:

```
/* NS_ENUM supports the use of one or two arguments. The first argument is always the integer type used for the values of the enum. The second argument is an optional type name for the macro. When specifying a type name, you must precede the macro with 'typedef' like so:


typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NSComparisonResult) {
    ...
};

If you do not specify a type name, do not use 'typedef'. For example:

NS_ENUM(NSInteger) {
    ...
};
*/
```

In short, don't use `typedef` if your enum is unnamed.  Also, make sure that the enum is declared at the top or bottom of your file, outside any Objective-C interfaces or implementation blocks.

```
NS_ENUM(NSInteger)
{   k_a = 123,
    k_b = 123,
    k_c = 61
};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger,  unused_name)
{   k_d = 123,
    k_e = 123,
    k_f = 61
};
```